# Why is my game over screen not showing when current health is 0?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am busy creating a health system and created a game over screen to show when current health is 0/player is dead.
But the game over screen is not showing (I don't know much about `if`)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class HealthSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int maxHealth = 100;
    public int currentHealth;

    public HealthBar healthBar;
    public GameObject gameOver;

    public bool damage;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        currentHealth = maxHealth;
        healthBar.SetMaxHealth(maxHealth);
    }

    void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        currentHealth -= damage;

        healthBar.SetHealth(currentHealth);
    }
    
    public void GameOver()
    {
        if (currentHealth == 0)
        {
            gameOver.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    public void RestartButton()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Playground");
    }
    
    public void OnDamage(InputValue value)
    {
        DamageInput(value.isPressed);
        TakeDamage(10);
    }

    public void DamageInput(bool newDamageState)
    {
        damage = newDamageState;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us the full code of your script. or at least enough to see what `gameOver` is meant to be. I would guess a GameObject? What is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are nowhere calling `GameOver()` in your code. Every time you decrement `currentHealth()`, check if it reached zero and do the necessary. For this, call `GameOver()` in your `TakeDamage()` method

```cs
void TakeDamage(int damage)
{
    currentHealth -= damage;
    
    GameOver();

    healthBar.SetHealth(currentHealth);
}
```

Also, check if `currentHealth` is less than or equal to `0`, not just `0`

```cs
public void GameOver()
{
    if (currentHealth <= 0)
    {
        gameOver.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```